# Is there an attack speed cap?

Tags: diablo-iii

While playing around with some item builds, I managed to reach a little over 2 attacks per second. This was a huge increase from the 1.10 APS staff I had been using, and a TON of fun. But realizing that I am only level 19 and only half of my slots had attack speed bonuses, I am sure it is possible to reach **much** higher levels of attack speed.

Is there a maximum attack speed? Or will we see level 60 characters machine-gunning everything in sight (without [Rapid Fire](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/rapid-fire))?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no hard cap, but obviously a practical cap based on the base speed of weapons and max values of available IAS bonus.

Fastest base weapon speed: 1.50 (daggers) or 1.60 (1H crossbow)

IAS from 2 rings + amulet: 9 x 3 = 27%

IAS from the weapon: 11% (rare/magic), or 20% (superior quality white items)

6% from legendary items in various slots:

- Chest: `Beckon Sail` or `Tal Rasha's Guardianship`
- Pants: `Inna's Glory`
- Helm: `Andariel's Visage` or `Mempo of Twilight`
- Bracer: `Lacuni Prowlers`
- Boots: `Boj Anglers`

Off-hand: 20% from `Dead Man's Legacy` for Demon Hunter off-hand

There is also the `Shrine of Frenzy` which adds a 25% IAS for 2 minutes.

So if you just want the theoretical max weapon speed:

- **Base weapon aps** of 1H crossbow: 1.60
- Bonus for **superior item** quality: 20%
- Total **bonus from equipment** in general: (9 * 3)% + (6 * 5)% = 57%
- Additional from **Dead Man's Legacy** for DH: 20%
- **Shrine** of Frenzy: 25% *(not sure if this is additive with items or multiplicative factor)*
- **Focus Mind** passive from Enchantress: 3%

Max bonus from items for DH: 57% + 20% = 77%
Max IAS incl shrine = 102%
Final weapon speed: (1.60 * 1.20) * 2.02 = **3.8784** aps

I did not include Focus Mind as I [don't know how it will apply](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76170/calculating-enchantress-focus-mind). This also excludes the effect of skills that add IAS like Barb's Frenzy. (A Barbarian would have to use daggers instead of 1H xbow).

Comment: actually fastest weapon speed are 1handed crossbows at 1.6 ;)

Comment: You are almost there.  quivers can have up to 20% attack speed from dead man's legacy

Comment: There's also a belt called The Witching Hour (Pre-RoS(Reaper of Souls)) that can roll 9% attack speed, and in RoS a craftable belt Fleeting Strap that can give 5-7% increased attack speed.

Answer (score 7):

Cap seems to be 5 attacks per second. Measured with 86% attack and Flying dragon active and the Istvan’s weapon set also. Even by removing 7% attack speed it still says 5 per second, no change. If anyone’s hit 6, I’d like to see.[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a hard cap at 5.00 attacks per second, nothing I do increases it past there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At this point there doesn't appear to be any known hard cap on attack speed. However, theorycrafters [have estimated](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4768688967) that with all equipment bearing the maximum attack speed bonus, you would max out at 6-7 attacks per second.

Comment: this probably should be updated since the max attack speed values have been halved in the IAS nerf