# What is the cap for increase attack speed in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an attack speed cap?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67249/is-there-an-attack-speed-cap)

If i remember correctly, in Diablo 2 expansion there was a cap on increase attack speed meaning if you stack more than X% then it becomes useless.  What exactly is the cap for melee and/or casters?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/67249/5291