# calculating Enchantress Focus Mind

Tags: diablo-iii

I am attempting to calculate the Enchantress's skill Focused Mind, however I appear to be having an issue with the 3% Increased Attack Speed (IAS).

If I apply the 3% the following ways, they all yield the wrong result:

- Applying to the [attack speed](http://www.diablowiki.net/Attack_Speed) of the current weapon.
- Apply to the items' total IAS on the character.
- Applying against the IAS of the character's weapon + Passives

All methods yield incorrect results, does anyone know how to apply the bonus and where?

Comment: Wouldn't this be applied against the base weapon speed?  All the IAS bonuses should be cumulative, resulting in your final attack speed.  So try adding all the IAS bonuses together (including that on your weapons), and then apply that against the base weapon attack speed.  That should provide your final attack speed.

Comment: Doing it this way returns wrong result, normal DPS 37015.57, with Enchantress in game: 37940.96, when I apply the 3% to the weapons AS I get: 38126.03

Comment: Oh, are you looking at how IAS increases DPS, not trying to calculate your final attack speed?

Comment: I am asking how do i apply the enchantress buff (or how does the game calculate it) to my current dps formula, ive tried 8 different connotations with no luck.

Comment: You're going to want to look [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30982/how-is-listed-dps-calculated-when-dual-wielding-weapons) and [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67843/what-does-the-damage-stat-on-the-character-sheet-actually-mean-how-is-dps-calcu).  This question is probably a duplicate of the second.

Comment: fbueckert - thanks for the input however those links do not answer my question, my formulas are as close to perfect as anyone elses, however my question is 'how' does the game apply the enchantress buff.  have worked out that it does not apply against the weapons base AS, the above and many other ways. I have also been googling for nearly 3 hours for the answer but I am starting to think no one out there actually knows. :s

Comment: I have found the answer to my question, your going to lol :(

Comment: What is the attack speed listed on your weapon? Does your weapon have increased attack speed on it as an affix on the weapon? How much attack speed does the rest of your gear give? And what are the "Attacks per second" values listed in the details page with and without focused mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question,

Firstly Blizzard have screwed up, adding 3% to your AS is in fact to add 0.03 as a direct figure to your (Weapons AS * Weapon IAS) value, this returns me a figure that is now only .1 of a decimal out of the in game figure which is unfortunately acceptable.

Thus you need simply:

(Weapon AS * WeaponIAS) + 0.03.

*Hate Blizz moment*

Comment: Hrm.  The Enchantress's IAS bonus is added after calculating weapon speed?  That doesn't seem right.  I'll do some testing when I get home to corroborate.

Comment: I did not think so either however setting it this way returns my attack speed to within 0.01 decimal point.

Comment: This is most likely wrong. While it might be roughly accurate in your case, it cannot be the general formula. If the formula was like that, it would not be a percentage. The skill would say "adds 0.03 attacks per second". You should reveal the actual values you used in the computation, because this seems highly unlikely.

Comment: @Alderath Just because it says it adds 3% does not mean it actually does. I think John is correct. I am having the same issue. If you add .03 cumulatively, a weapon with 1.4 attacks per second should come out to 1.44 (1.4 * 1.03), but the in-game screen says 1.43.